# How to change javacard default keys?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I have a javacard and it's `S_ENC`, `S_MAC` and `DEK` keys are `404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F`. the question is how I can change these key via gpj , gpshell or jcmanager?

Comment: Try and do some research before posting questions, or indicate that you did. This question is almost trivial if you've read the GP documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With gpshell, you can use the put_sc_key command:

```
put_sc_key -keyver <current key version> -newkeyver <new key version> -mac_key <mac key> -enc_key <enc key> -kek_key <kek key> [-current_kek <kek key>]
```

I don't think that changing keys is possible with GPJ. The GUI of jcManager has nice self-explanatory text-fields and buttons that should be fairly easy to understand (i.e. "New keys:", "Add/modify keys").

Answer (score 2):

PUT KEY Command is a GP command to change key.
The APDU format is "80/84 D8 P1 P2 Lc Data Le", For more details you can see "GlobalPlatform Card Specification"

> The PUT KEY command is used to either:
>
> • Replace an existing key with a new key: The new key has the same or a different Key Version Number but the same Key Identifier as the key being replaced;
>
> • Replace multiple existing keys with new keys: The new keys have the same or a different Key Version Number (identical for all new keys) but the same Key Identifiers as the keys being replaced;
>
> • Add a single new key: The new key has a different combination Key Identifier / Key Version Number than that of the existing keys;
>
> • Add multiple new keys: The new keys have different combinations of Key Identifiers / Key Version Number (identical to all new keys) than that of the existing keys;
> When the key management operation requires multiple PUT KEY commands, chaining of the multiple PUT KEY commands is recommended to ensure integrity of the operation.
> In this version of the Specification the public values of asymmetric keys are presented in clear text